# ¿Cómo interpretar mejor símbolos matemáticos y cifras en textos publicitarios?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral, hispanoamérica

De acuerdo a un texto en inglés, tal como se muestra a continuación:

```
> 150,000,000 $ in sales.
```

Quería saber, las personas que hablan completamente español, ¿Cómo entenderían esta oración traducida al español para una publicidad de una revista?

```
> $ 150 000 000 en ingresos.
```

Quiere decir más de 150 millones en ingresos. ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de transformar esta oración comercial y hacerla más entendible para hispano-hablantes?

¿Cuál preferirían dentro de las siguientes opciones como un texto para una publicidad?

Opción A: **> $ 150 000 000 en ingresos.**
Opción B: **+ $ 150 000 000 en ingresos.**
Opción C: **MÁS de $ 150 000 000 en ingresos.**

¿El símbolo ">" en color rojo y en grande les llama la atención? o pasaría desapercibido.

Sería genial tener un consenso entre los hispano-hablantes de diferentes culturas.

Yo opto por la opción C y utilizar millones como muchos ya me han sugerido. Estoy tratando de convencer a un infografista que no habla español, que es lo más atractivo para los hispanos en leer.

Comment: No voy a votar para cerrar la pregunta, pero "Estoy buscando una opinión", "interpretación de muchos" y "Me gustaría la opinión" darían pie a cerrar la pregunta por ser **"opinion based"** (we try to avoid [subjective questions](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). Yo replantaría la pregunta en base a normas de puntuación establecida para  este caso, en lugar de opinión sobre lo que _puede parecer mejor_.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. ¿Qué tal ahora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es difícil responder de una forma genérica porque cada persona lo leerá de acuerdo con su formación y preferencia.

Por ejemplo, para mí una expresión del tipo `> $150` tiene sentido, así como `+ $150` (aunque menos). Pero si se lo enseñas a mi abuela, seguramente le sonará a chino porque no está demasiado familiarizada con las expresiones del tipo matemático.

Es por eso que debes ver cuál es el contexto en el que lo utilizarás.

De todos modos, si tal contexto no es conocido o quieres asegurarte que sea entenedido por todo el mundo, sin duda deberías ir por la expresión que no utiliza símbolos. Es decir:

> Opción C: MÁS de $ 150 000 000 en ingresos.

---

Añado: escribir `$ 150 000 000` suena algo raro. Si son 150 millones, escribe `150.000.000` o directamente `150 millones`. No es común escribir espacios entre los bloques de los miles y puede prestarse a confusión.

Sin embargo, está bien decirlo. A mí no me lo parecía, pero [guillem comenta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14691/interpretaci%C3%B3n-de-un-texto#comment16669_14692) que sí dando la siempre fiable fuente de [Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/miles-6498/):

> «Al escribir números de más de cuatro cifras, se agruparán estas de
>   tres en tres, empezando por la derecha, y separando los grupos por
>   espacios en blanco: 8 327 451 (y no por puntos o comas, como,
>   dependiendo de las zonas, se hacía hasta ahora: *8.327.451;
>   *8,327,451). Los números de cuatro cifras se escriben sin espacios de separación: 2458 (no *2 458). En ningún caso deben repartirse en
>   líneas diferentes las cifras que componen un número: *8 327 / 451.»

Comment: En realidad los espacios son correctos. Fundéu, que sé que te gusta ;) http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/miles-6498/ Edit: aunque para publicidad puede que escribir «millones» con letra funcione mejor.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo pienso lo mismo. Estoy discutiendo con una infografista para una publicidad, que textualmente la palabra "más" para Latino América (o la comunidad hispano-hablante en general) es más entendible. Ojo que es un texto orientado a gente de negocios. Pero por eso quiero una opinión estándar de varios hispano-hablantes para determinar la opción más simple y entendible para todos.

Comment: @guillem siempre al quite :) Gracias, actualicé mi respuesta con esta información. Hay que ver lo que cuesta mantenerse actualizado sobre cuál es la manera de escribir algo, a la que uno se acostumbra se lo cambian : D

Comment: Efectivamente hace algunos años alguien me indicó lo mismo con respecto a lo de las cifras. Distinto a lo que aprendí en el colegio. ¡Hace mucho realmente! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Hasta ahora tengo 2 opiniones que prefieren el más. Gracias.

Comment: Finalmente ¡ganamos muchachos! Logramos que el infografista testarudo  pudiera cambiar su arte a MÁS y MILLONES, tal como aconsejaron. Muchas gracias por el aporte y por el enlace también a @guillem. Muy agradecido.

Answer (score 3):

Supongo que mi respuesta entra dentro del ámbito de la opinión personal, pero creo que el «más» es lo que mejor se entiende.

Respecto al símbolo de divisa, en España es habitual ponerlo detrás de las cantidades, como las unidades de medida: 150 000 000 $. [El ponerlo delante no es incorrecto](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/uso-de-los-simbolos-de-divisa-13368/), y supongo que dependerá más bien de la región y del público objetivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Efectivamente tu opinión es muy valiosa para mí. Debido a que estoy buscando una interpretación estándar para todos los hispanos-hablantes.

Comment: De todas maneras, la opción de @fedorqui de escribir «millones» con letra me parece brillante, porque llama muchísimo más la atención que una ristra de ceros.

Comment: Yo también lo discutí muchisimo con la infografista. El texto originalmente estaba en inglés y en cifras; y le dije que en español es más llamativo la palabra millones. Osea lo leemos y atrapamos el concepto inmediatamente, incluso, si lo resaltamos en negrita sería mejor. Pero no me entiende porque no es hispano-hablante.